# Why is pytesseract displaying image to string as blank?

Tags: python, flask, ocr, tesseract

So in my application that i am making called IntelliQuest and it involves using OCR to extract text from a image. I used tesseract and made a simple script on python flask which just involves decoding a base64 text into a image and trying to extract the text from it.

The main issue that is being caused is that whenever i scan the image, in the console the only thing that is being logged is a blank text.

**My main question is that if their is a problem in my code which is casuing a blank text, is it a problem with the installation or is it a problem with the image itself?**

First since i was on windows, i tried to see if it was a problem with the installation and with my path and enviormental variables, and i checked it, and it wasn't really the problem. My server log didn't show any issues with the installation later so i decided that wasn't the issue.

Here is an example with what issue is persisting:
https://streamable.com/y6vjgj

Here is my code:

```
@app.route('/upload_image', methods=['POST'])
def upload_image():
    if 'imageDataUrl' in request.json:
        # Decode the base64 image data and save it
        image_data = request.json['imageDataUrl'].split(',')[1]
        image_binary = base64.b64decode(image_data)

        # Save the image for debugging (optional)
        with open('uploaded_image.jpg', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(image_binary)

        # Perform OCR on the image
        image = Image.open(BytesIO(image_binary))
        extracted_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')

        return jsonify({'status': 'success', 'text': extracted_text})

    return jsonify({'status': 'error', 'message': 'No image data uploaded'})
```

If useful, html template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Get Started{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<style>
    #get-started-page {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 50px; /* Add margin-top for space */
    }
</style>
  <section id="get-started-page">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="card bg-dark text-white transparent-card" style="margin: auto; margin-bottom: 50px; padding: 20px;">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h2 class="text-center mb-4">Get Started with IntelliQuest</h2>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label">Take a Picture</label>
                <div>
                  <video id="cameraFeed" width="100%" height="auto" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;" autoplay playsinline></video>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="captureButton">Capture Image</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      const cameraFeed = document.getElementById("cameraFeed");
      const captureButton = document.getElementById("captureButton");

      let imageDataUrl;  // Move the declaration here

      // Check if the browser supports getUserMedia
      if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
          .then((stream) => {
            cameraFeed.srcObject = stream;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error accessing camera:", error);
          });

        // Capture image from the video stream
        captureButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
          const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
          canvas.width = cameraFeed.videoWidth;
          canvas.height = cameraFeed.videoHeight;
          const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
          context.drawImage(cameraFeed, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

          // Get the base64-encoded image data
          imageDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

          // Send the image data to the server
          fetch('/upload_image', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ imageDataUrl }),
          })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data))
        });
      } else {
        console.error("getUserMedia not supported on this browser");
      }
    });
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: @Community Bot here, i just clarified my problem. (edited)